# self refers to superclass not subclass

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

This code will give the error `AttributeError: 'Treeview' object has no attribute 'OnFeatureDoubleClick'` because `self` refers to the superclass, not the subclass where `OnFeatureDoubleClick` is located.
How do I do this?

```
class MyTreeView (ttk.Treeview):

    def __init__ ( self, frame, my_column_headers, my_list):

        super(MyTreeView, self).__init__()

        print ("MyTreeView.__init__")

        self=ttk.Treeview(frame) # create the widget

        self["columns"]=my_column_headers

        # Level 1
        PARENT="" # top level
        INDEX = 1 # insert at end
        i = 0
        for thing in my_list:
            self.insert(PARENT, INDEX, i, text=str(i), values=(thing))
            i += 1

        self["show"] = ["headings"] # don't show first column     
        self.pack(side=Tkinter.TOP, fill=Tkinter.BOTH, expand=TRUE)
        # self is the super class tkinter.ttk.Treeview, 
        # so it will give error AttributeError: 'Treeview' object has no attribute 'OnFeatureDoubleClick' when clicked 
        self.bind("<Double-1>", lambda event : self.OnFeatureDoubleClick(event))

    def OnFeatureDoubleClick(self, event):
        print ("MyTreeView.OnFeatureDoubleClick: self: " + str(self))
        print ("MyTreeView.OnFeatureDoubleClick: event: " + str(event) + "\t" + str(event.x) +  "\t" + str(event.y))
        item = self.identify('item', event.x, event.y)
        print("MyTreeView.OnFeatureDoubleClick: ", self.item(item,"text"))
```

Comment: You can use `@staticmethod` for `OnFeatureDoubleClick(...)` but why you wanna call it like that when you can call it from the instance of  `MyTreeView`. ??

Comment: I'm learning as I go here. Can you demonstrate how to call from the instance of `MyTreeView` if that is the better way to go?

Comment: @Saad: that is a bad suggestion. That's not the problem. The problem is that this code is reassigning `self` when it shouldn't. Creating a static method doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: @BryanOakley: Sorry I misunderstood the question at the first. I thought the OP was trying to call the function outside the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using classes properly. You should not be reassigning `self` in this statement:

```
self=ttk.Treeview(frame) # create the widget
```

With that, you have created two treeview widgets -- the instance of `MyTreeView`, and an internal treeview. That is because `MyTreeView` is itself a `Treeview` since you inherit from `Treeview`. This is called an *is a* relationship, because `MyTreeView` *is a* `Treeview`.

You need to remove that line of code.

You also need to pass at least some of the arguments to the super constructor:

```
super(MyTreeView, self).__init__(frame, columns=my_column_headers)
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on [Brayan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56261053/10364425), as you've inherited `Treeview()` to your `MyTreeView()` class then the class itself is a `Treeview` and has all the functionalities of `Treeview` widget. When inheriting a widget of Tkinter you have to give arguments of that widget to the `__init__` constructor if you want to give parameter of the widget. For example `Treeview` widget has these `(master=None, **kw)` arguments so it goes like...

```
class MyTreeView(ttk.Treeview):
    def __init__(self, master=None, my_list=[], **kw):
        super(MyTreeView, self).__init__(master=master, **kw)
```

Where `my_list = []` is an additional argument given by you. Also I didn't give `my_column_headers` argument because it can given as `column=my_column_headers` at the time of creating an instance of the class like `tree = MyTreeView(root, my_list=list, columns= my_column_headers)`.

Also at line `self.bind("<Double-1>", lambda event : self.OnFeatureDoubleClick(event))` you don't need `lambda` as the callback of `bind` always pass event as a parameter to the given function. `lambda` is needed when you don't want to pass `event` as a parameter to the function.

I modified your class from I can understand from the given code.

```
class MyTreeView(ttk.Treeview):
    def __init__(self, master=None, my_list=[], **kw):
        super(MyTreeView, self).__init__(master=master, **kw)

        # Level 1
        PARENT="" # top level
        INDEX = 1 # insert at end
        i = 0

        for thing in my_list:
            self.insert(PARENT, INDEX, i, text=str(i), values=(thing))

        self.bind("<Double-1>", self.OnFeatureDoubleClick)

    def OnFeatureDoubleClick(self, event):
        print ("MyTreeView.OnFeatureDoubleClick: self: " + str(self))
        print ("MyTreeView.OnFeatureDoubleClick: event: " + str(event) + "\t" + str(event.x) +  "\t" + str(event.y))
        item = self.identify('item', event.x, event.y)
        print("MyTreeView.OnFeatureDoubleClick: ", self.item(item,"text"))
```